# game project : Explanation Required

Tags: c, opengl

I'm working on a OpenGL project and i need some brief explanation on the core components of the subject as i need to explain to somebody needy.

Following is the part of the program

The below are the **global variables and header files** used in the program

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define PI 3.14159265f
#include<stdio.h>

GLfloat ballRadius = 0.2,xradius=0.2,xxradius=1.0; 
GLfloat ballX = 0.0f;   
GLfloat ballY = 0.0f;
GLfloat ballXMax,ballXMin,ballYMax,ballYMin;  
GLfloat xSpeed = 0.02f;  
GLfloat ySpeed = 0.007f;
int refreshMills = 30;  
GLfloat angle=0.0;
int xa,ya; 
int flag=0,flag1=0;
int score = 0;
void *currentfont;
GLfloat xo=0, yo=0, x, y;
GLdouble clipAreaXLeft,clipAreaXRight,clipAreaYBottom,clipAreaYTop;
void balldisp() ;
void scoredisp();
```

**This is the reshape function. I need to do what exactly it is doing, what it is calculating and storing. Confused here**

```
void reshape(GLsizei width,GLsizei height)
{                                                           
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;  
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);   
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
    glLoadIdentity();               
    if(width >=height)
    {
        clipAreaXLeft = -1.0 * aspect;
        clipAreaXRight = 1.0 * aspect;
        clipAreaYBottom = -1.0;
        clipAreaYTop = 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        clipAreaXLeft = -1.0;
        clipAreaXRight = 1.0 ;
        clipAreaYBottom = -1.0 / aspect;
        clipAreaYTop = 1.0/ aspect;
    }
    gluOrtho2D(clipAreaXLeft,clipAreaXRight,clipAreaYBottom,clipAreaYTop+0.10);
    ballXMin = clipAreaXLeft + ballRadius;
    ballXMax =  clipAreaXRight - ballRadius;
    ballYMin =  clipAreaYBottom + ballRadius;
    ballYMax =  clipAreaYTop - ballRadius;  
}
```

**The below is the code to display the ball. What it is calculating and how the speed and direction is set. Confused here**

```
void balldisp() 
{
    glTranslatef(ballX,ballY,0.0f);    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);    
    color();
    glVertex2f(0.0f,0.0f);      
    int numSegments = 100;      
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=numSegments;i++) 
    {
        angle = i*2.0f*PI/numSegments;
        glVertex2f(cos(angle)*ballRadius,sin(angle)*ballRadius);
    }
    glEnd();    

    ballX += xSpeed;
    ballY += ySpeed;

    if(ballX > ballXMax)
    {   xa=ballX;
        ballX = ballXMax;
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;

    }
    else if(ballX < ballXMin)
    {   xa=ballX;
        ballX = ballXMin;
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;

    }
    if(ballY > ballYMax)
    {   ya=ballY;
        ballY = ballYMax;
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;

    }
    else if(ballY < ballYMin)
    {   ya=ballY;
        ballY = ballYMin;
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;

    }
```

I want to know the reshape function and ball display. What are they doing and how things are done there.

P.S. The project is about random motion of the ball which strikes the boundaries of the window and moves in other direction

Comment: you want *us* to explain *your code* to you?

Comment: @TZHX it is definitely not OP's code .. :)

Comment: @AshishNegi I know, friend. :)

Comment: ya not my code. Its sharable so i copied and want the expalantion. Just help me out instead of writing comments

Comment: there is something called OPEN SOURCE

Comment: @sunny open source licenses generally require *attribution* at the very least. you don't do that here. also: "I don't understand [large chunk of code]" is not a clear, focused question.

Comment: @TZHX, Often I also have the same need ^^

Answer (score 1):

The `reshape` function is registered with GLUT (using `glutReshapeFunc`) so that it gets called *by* GLUT whenever the size of the window changes. *Note that placing OpenGL functions for setting the viewport and/or the projection matrix in the reshape function is bad style and should be avoided. All OpenGL drawing related functions (which glViewport and the matrix setup are) belong into the display functions.*

Similarly the display function is registered with GLUT (using `glutDisplayFunc`) so that it gets called *by* GLUT whenever the windows needs to be redrawn (either because it got visible, contents need refreshing or redraw has been requested with `glutPostRedisplay`).

Comment: thanks for the contribution but the book theory i know.

Comment: I need to know regarding this program. What the reshape() and balldisp() are doing here ?

Comment: @sunny: Uh, the code is pretty much self explanatory. The variable names are well chosen and self documenting. `reshape` adjusts the ball clipping region to match the window shape. `balldisp` draws the "ball" using OpenGL (and does some calculations that should be carried out in the game loop and not the drawing function). I really can't give you any more information than that, without being redundant. The code is well readable. Read it, try to understand it.

Comment: Why is setting the viewport and projection in the reshape function bad style? They only change when the window is resized. So setting them on each redraw is redundant. That's exactly what the reshape function is intended for.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Think about what happens if you want to perform an intermediary render-to-texture (FBO) step, like for a shadow map? Or what if there's going to be a minimap in the lower right corner? In general all programs using OpenGL will eventually reach a level of complexity where the viewport is set in the drawing code… several times. By moving any viewport/projections out of the reshape and into the display function the relationship between glViewport and the rest becomes clearer and this upfront preparation avoids problematic constructs to appear in reshape right from the start.

Comment: Ok, certainly, if you're going to change the viewport multiple times while drawing, setting it in reshape would not be useful anymore. For a simple example, where there's only rendering to the default framebuffer, I don't see any harm in it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: It's also an educational thing. Putting glViewport in tutorials makes many learners think that it "belongs" there, and then they are inable to get around that mental roadblock when dealing with minimaps or rendering to FBOs. By breaking the anti-pattern early, this kind of learning obstacle is avoided.